# friend function pointer parameter in constructor

Tags: c++

i'm trying to create a costructor in the form

```
class A {
public:
    A(void (*initializer)(A&))
    {
        initializer(*this);
    }
};
```

where initializer take a reference to the instance he's passed and can make custom operation on variable it is initializing. Is there a way to make such a function friend so it can access to private variables too?

Comment: This seems like a very unusual way to initialize a class object. You could pass the privates as parameters to the function. But I would rather have several constructors, and chose one of them when creating an object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way:

```
class Impl
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(void (*initializer)(Impl&))
    {
        initializer(_impl);
    }

private:
    Impl _impl;
};
```

This hides `_impl` from everyone except `initializer`.  And since nobody other than `initializer` can access `_impl` at all, the members of of `class Impl` can be public, making it easy for `initializer` to mutate them.

Comment: that's a nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other than listing all the functions you want to pass pointers to as friends separately, no. An alternative may be to separate the data into a base class with public members you inherit privately from:

```
struct AData
{
    int m_privateInt;
    ...
};

class A : private AData {
public:
    A(void (*initializer)(AData&))
    {
        initializer(*this);
    }
};
```

You may need to also pass a reference to `A`, if you want to access its member functions in `initializer`.